# php framework help

Tags: php, frameworks

Ok so before anyone states the fact that the php framework question has already been answered, note that I am asking questions specifically on which framework would be best given the requirements that I am providing. I am currently in the proccess of building a large project. I will be in the future working on several medium/large and a few small projects. I am an experienced php developer and fully know OOP inside and out and have a great knowledge of mysql database so learning a system is not a problem.

Now that is out of the way down to what I am actually looking for. I have currently been using a "framework" that is not so great and was provided to me for my projects. I would like to get rid of the "framework" and actually start using an actual framework. I was thinking of building my own framework but was considering (and really leaning towards) using an already preexisting framework. I have looked at a bunch of frameworks and even played with a few of them out there. Once I choose a framework I am going to want to keep using it and not have to switch 6 months down the road so before I choose I will be doing some thorough testing before making the final decision. I would like to get some input from some users as to which ones would fit my needs best.

In a framework I am looking for the following items:

1. Speed - because of being larger projects I will need to keep speed in mind. I can write efficient code but if the framework is slow it really wont matter now will it :)
2. Authentication - I would like to be able to use some built in authentication if possible through the framework. I dont necessarily need granular permissions based on users but more or less through groups (granular permissions is not a turn off just not a requirement).
3. Ajax - I like to use ajax in my applications so I would like some kind of ajax implementation in the framework and personally I prefer jquery. It doesnt necessarily need to have built in ajax features but a way to kill the page with the ajax output before anything is output for efficiency.
4. Forms - I have seen that alot of frameworks have built in features for managing forms but just thought I would mention it here to save myself the headache.
5. Administration - This is possibly one of the most required features that I really need. I need to be able to create a backend to manage the site. I dont want to have to hack something together to make this work.
6. Api - I will be in need of an api for accessing/modifying data that I will be allowing.
7. Database - Built in database methods. Doesnt necessarily need to do it automatically, just give me access to be able to retrieve/update the data that is need.

These are not neccessarily requirements but more or less nice features:

1. I would like to be able to encase all of my data that goes with a certain item into a "module" of a sort. So that I could easily copy it to another site and have it all ready to go.
2. An easy to navigate structure. I would like to be able to go into controllers and not see 50 files but instead see maybe 10 folders with the files encased in the folders so that it is better separated.

I cant really think of anything else at this time but if I think of anything else I will update the post. I would really like to get feedback from people who are using any frameworks out there. If you havent messed with a framework please do not recommend it as you have no experience with it and will not know if it would suit my needs. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
I just wanted to edit this post to clarify some stuff. In the requirements/features that I am looking for I do not necessarily need all of the features to be built into the framework. From some of the responses it seemed as if people were thinking that all of this stuff has to be pre-ready. I more or less am looking for a framework that supports all of the features that I am looking for that is easily accomplished with the components in the framework. For example the administration, it does not have to have a default administration area but allow for me to create an administration easily from the components that I will be adding to the site.

Comment: While not terribly interesting, this is thoughtful and well-written question. Pity-upvote +1, because it will be answered with the usual five anyway. Except for the admin backend requirement most frameworks provide all of the listed features.

Comment: only one advice, **wrote yourself, you know better than anyone on your application requirement**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my own experience ( CodeIgniter , Zend Framework ), **but realy all major frameworks will allow you to do everithing you asked** .

1. Speed - CodeIgniter is the fastest i worked with , this is not the strongest feature of ZF , in fact where i work we all got to the conclusion that ZF is slow .
2. Auth - Zend Framework handles auth better than what i saw in other frameworks
3. Ajax - All major Frameworks will allow you do disable the layout/view , Zend is slightly better here , as you can have special json views.
4. Forms - CodeIgniter framework handles forms easyer than ZF , however all frameworks should deal with this problem with ease . Symfony needs to be mentioned here with it's form generator .
5. Administration - Symfony just becouse it has a nice crud form generator based on the tables you're passing ( "admin generator" how they are advertising it ) , witch will speed development quite a bit .
6. ???
7. Database - ZF handles databases nicer in my opionion , however i've heard good things about Symfony too . CodeIgniter here is not that strict witch is not a good thing in my opinion .
8. Modular App - Building modules in ZF is realy easy , and the feature that i like most is that a module structure looks like the whole app itself ( eg. the whole app is a module ... )
9. Easy to navigate structure - All of them once you are used to it , however i don't like the fact that CodeIgniter keeps all it's controllers in one place , when in ZF you can add modules and separate things from one and another .

Comment: @Yada: thanks , but my answer never goes in depth , the first thing you whant when you pick a framework is good documentation , ZF lacks badly here where CodeIgniter and CakePHP do have it . Plus i never mentioned CakePHP mainly becouse i never worked with it but definetly worths a look .

Answer (score 1):

Well, I worked with several PHP frameworks in the past and there aren't many good frameworks. You could risk a look at Zend Framework

1. ok
2. ok (but not enterprise level)
3. ok, but dojo
4. complicated
5. no, its a framework, not an application
6. ok, but not really a ERM
7. encapsulates PDO in an ugly way (bad implemented factory pattern)

ZF is developed by Zend itself, but I wasn't really happy with that too, because it has a lot of shortcomings (cruel DBAL, complicated form handling, supports dojo instead of jQuery) and if you are used to Java/JBOSS or .NET it just sucks (only mentioning this because you are planning a big project).

If you have some time until your project needs to be deployed and if you dont need to start immediately, you could also try FLOW3 (still alpha) which is developed by the TYPO3 Team. I've played a little bit with FLOW3 and can say that it is the only PHP FW which has at least a good architecture and some good ideas/paradigms (AOP e.g.).

If I understand you in the right way you would need something like a CMS for your backend. Maybe it would be a good idea to evaluate exiting CMS's and check out if you could extend them (use the CMS as framework (TYPO3 e.g.)).

You wont find a FW that matches exactly your needs, therefore you should consider choosing a CMS/FW and customize it in the way you need it. If the project is as big as I imagine there should be enough resources for such task.